# Duplicate values in my drop down

Tags: php, html, mysql

I hope anyone can help me with this, What happened in here is that when I click my drop down (the employee dd). It will have a duplicate values (the name). It happened when I add the "cashadvance" table. :(

[image]

Here's my code.

```
<tr>
                <td><label for="ename">Names:</label></td>
                <td><select name="ename" id="ename">
                      <option>Choose</option>
                      <?php
                        include("alqdb.php");
                        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT EmpID, EmpFName, TypeofEmployee, Salary, ContDeduc FROM employee, cashadvance");
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                          echo "<option value='{$row["EmpFName"]}' data-emp-id='{$row["EmpID"]}' data-type='{$row["TypeofEmployee"]}' data-sal='{$row["Salary"]}' data-deduc='{$row["ContDeduc"]}'>";
                          echo $row["EmpFName"] . "</option>";
                        }
                      ?>
                </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: what does `$result` have?

Comment: I think using jquery/ajax, can also solve this. :)

Comment: you're selecting from 2 tables here (which seems to be part of the problem). If you want uniqueness, use a DISTINCT and/or GROUP BY.

Comment: jquery/ajax will not solve this, you want a serverside solution.

Comment: sorry2, I will immediately remove that. btw, using DISTINCT is not working. can you show it? if I use the GROUP BY? thank you in advance. :)

Comment: you will need to do a subquery / JOIN and apply DISTINCT/GROUP BY to the query that holds the same values.

Comment: sorry, but how can I do it? I'm still new in php though. :)

Comment: Yes, `GROUP BY cashadvance.EmpID` if `EmpID` is present in the 2nd table and for example with `ORDER BY column_of_choice` or `GROUP BY cashadvance.EmpFName`. @FrancisVargas Read the manual on SELECT http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: the GROUP BY cashadvance.EmpID have an error. :( btw, ContID is the pk of the cashadvance table. :)

Comment: `GROUP BY cashadvance.ContID` then with ORDER BY column_x < an example. Or `SELECT DISTINCT cashadvance.column_X` with GROUP BY. `column_X` means the column of choice in the 2nd table.

Comment: @FrancisVargas, please make a structure of your two tables and put it in your question.

Comment: This is an sql question so you need to update your question with your table structures and what you are trying to select from each of them

Comment: @FrancisVargas you've been given comments by myself; no word on that. You've been asked to post db schema for both tables; still no edit for it. You want to comment me directly, use the @ followed by my name. I've stayed here/stared at your question long enough. Either you do that, or continue with the answer that was given below. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good day!
I think you missed "WHERE" part.
Something like:

```
SELECT EmpID, EmpFName, TypeofEmployee, Salary, ContDeduc 
FROM employee, cashadvance
WHERE employee.id = cashadvance.ref_employee
```

(check the cashadvacne`s column name)

Or use SQL`s Join.

Comment: yeah! you are right with that. but the third employee is not showing. :(

Comment: Does any row with third`s employee id exist in cashadvance table?
If you need only names, you don`t need the 2nd table.
If you need all the names and additional info, then you should use LEFT JOIN.
[code]
SELECT EmpID, EmpFName, TypeofEmployee, Salary, ContDeduc 
FROM employee
LEFT JOIN cashadvance
ON employee.id = cashadvance.ref_employee
[/code]
Then, if in the 2nd table you don`t have any row related to for example Norman (the 3rd employee), then the 2nd table fields will be filled by NULL and at the same time the data from the 1st table will be present, so you`ll have all names

Answer (score 2):

You should use [DISTINCT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html) in your query to get unique results.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT EmpID, EmpFName, TypeofEmployee, Salary, ContDeduc FROM employee, cashadvance");
```

Comment: How do you know that he has duplicates saved in database?

Comment: Because the options are populated from the database. So they clearly have duplicate entries.

Comment: The OP is selecting from 2 tables here, did you not notice that? `FROM employee, cashadvance` and it could have a bearing on the issue.

Comment: @ObjectManipulator, your answer does not make sense, but Fred -ii-'s comment does.

Comment: OP: *"It happened when I add the "cashadvance" table"* - See?

Comment: *"sorry2, I will immediately remove that. btw, using DISTINCT is not working. can you show it? if I use the GROUP BY? thank you in advance. :) – Francis Vargas"*

Comment: `DISTINCT` won't work because the query selects columns from `cashadvance`, which are different for different employees.

Comment: @Barmar I came back to see the status of Q&A's. Scratching my head as to why this received so many upvotes (one of those is not mine) despite what's already been said about the 2 tables and DISTINCT. The OP seems to have vanished.